# linked list manual entered by keyboard

Tags: java, linked-list

when creating the list manually by keyboard I have the following drawback, the variable nodo only stores the current value. ListaEnlazada1 nodo = new ListaEnlazada1();

```
package lista.enlazada1;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ListaEnlazada1 {

public String marca;
public String modelo;
public int kilometraje;
public ListaEnlazada1 nodosiguiente;


public static void main(String[] args) {
/* enter the number of nodes to be created */
Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de nodos a ingresar)");
int n,contador=0;
n=leer.nextInt();

/* the three data of the node is entered */
for (int i =1; i <= n; i++){
   ListaEnlazada1 nodo = new ListaEnlazada1();
    System.out.print("ingrese la marca ");
      nodo.marca=leer.next();
      System.out.print("ingrese el modelo ");
      nodo.modelo=leer.next();
      System.out.print("ingrese el kilometraje ");
      nodo.kilometraje=leer.nextInt();

/* the node is created  */  

 if(contador==0){
 nodo.nodosiguiente = null;
 contador ++;
 } else {
 nodo.nodosiguiente = nodo;
 contador ++;
 }    

/* nodes are printed  */
for ( i =1; i <= n; i++){
System.out.println("marca " +nodo.marca+ "\n");
    System.out.println("modelo " +nodo.modelo+ "\n");
    System.out.println("kilometraje " +nodo.kilometraje+ "\n");
    System.out.println("apuntador " +nodo.nodosiguiente + "\n");    

}

}

}

}
```

I need to change the code so that the variable changes the name every time I enter the for, for example the first iteration node1, the second iteration node2, etc. what I have tried nothing has worked. the exercise must be done without the linked list library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

To display the current node's position in the series, consider the following:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    System.out.println("----------");
    System.out.println("Ingrese los datos del nodo " + i);
    /* user input */
}
```

You might as well consider displaying information about each node after all nodes have been entered so that the program's output is more readable. Since you store each node in the node before it, you could try this to cycle through them:

```
ListaEnlazada actual = primerNodo; // save the first node somewhere before user input
imprimirNodo(actual);
while((actual = actual.nodosiguiente) != null) {
    imprimirNodo(actual);
}
```

where the `imprimirNodo(nodo)` method is the following:

```
static void imprimirNodo(ListaEnlazada1 nodo) {
    System.out.println("----------");
    System.out.println("Marca: " + nodo.marca); // No need to break the line manually.
    System.out.println("Kilometraje: " + nodo.kilometraje);
    /* Note that printing nodo.nodosiguiente may lead to
    * unreadable output unless you override toString() */
    System.out.println("Apuntador: " + nodo.nodosiguiente);
}
```